# Graph Sketching, $y=2x^2+8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> (a) $y=2x^2+8$. Sketch the graph of this equation. Show the coordinates of the point(s) and where the graph crosses the coordinate axes, and write down the coordinates of the turning point and the equation of the line of symmetry.

By finding the determinant, $(b^2-4ac)$, I found that the curve doesnt intersect x-axis at all.  And the coordinates of $y=(0,8)$. But I'm struggling to find out line of symmetry because the equation is already in complete square so how do I find the line of symmetry and then the turning points?

Comment: for crosses the coordinate axes , put $x=0$ then find $y$, after that put $y=0$ and find $x$, for symmetry put $x=-x$ and see you get same equation so it is symmetric about $y$ axis

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the terms "turning point" or "line of symmetry".  **However**, whatever is being asked, in this specific situation, I suggest that you stretch your intuition as follows:  Contrast $y = (2x^2 + 8)$ with $y = x^2.$  There are two *alterations*.  First, because the coefficient of $x^2$ is $2$ rather than 1, the curve is **steeper.**  Second, the **only significance** of the $...+ 8$ term, is that the **entire curve** is *shifted upwards* 8 units.

Comment: Let it cuts on $x $ axis then at that point $y$ is zero so it you put $y=0$ you will get what are the values for $x$ ,similarly when it cuts the $y$ axis at that points it have $x$ coordinate $0$, so put $x=0$ and find corrosponding values of $y$

Comment: When I put y=0, it gets x^2=-4; its mathematically incorrect to solve right? So what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Good question.  You are supposed to conclude that if $f(x) = 2x^2 + 8,$ then $f(x)$ **never** intersects the x axis.  Did you notice my earlier comment about the entire curve being shifted upwards 8 units?

Answer (score 3):

Method1: Particularly to this problem, it is an even function in $x$. i.e. if you replace $x$ by $-x$, the equation still remains the same. Hence, it must be symmetric about the line $x=0$ or, the $y$ axis.

Method2 : Transformations:

Draw $y=x^2$

[image]

Stretch it vertically to get $y=2x^2$

[image]

Now shift it up by 8 units to get $y=2x^2+8$

[image]

Comment: Man thanks a lot! I really needed those graph photos to verify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

In general,

$$y=a(x-b)^2+c$$

has line of symmetry $x=b$ because we can see that $b+\delta$ and $b-\delta$ would be evaluated to the same amount and the turning point is $(b, c)$.

Now, for your question,

$$y=2x^2+8=2(x-0)^2+8$$

can you idenfity the line of symmetry and turning point now?

Comment: So coordinates of y and turning points are (0,8)?

Comment: the turning point and the $y$-intercept is $(0,8)$.  I believe you can find the line of symmetry too :).

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to note that you can write the equation $(y-c)=a(x-b)^2$ which makes explicit the parallel relationships of $x$ to $b$ and $y$ to $c$.